# ESP8266 responds with gibberish and 'ready' to AT commands from C program

Tags: avr, esp8266, atmega328p

I have gotten the ESP8266 working by sending commands manually from the TTY. Now, I'm trying to connect to wifi using the following C program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUD 115200
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

static void usart_init(void) {
    unsigned int ubrr = F_CPU / 16 / BAUD - 1;
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t) (ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t) ubrr;
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

static void usart_send_byte(uint8_t data) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
        ;
    UDR0 = data;
}

static uint8_t usart_recv_byte(void) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)))
        ;
    return UDR0;
}

static void usart_send_str(const char *s) {
    for (; *s; s++)
        usart_send_byte(*s);
}

static void usart_recv_str(char *s, uint8_t n) {
    uint8_t c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n && (c = usart_recv_byte()) != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i - 1] = 0;
}

static void esp8266_test() {
    const uint8_t maxlen = 4096;
    char s[maxlen];

    s[0] = 0;
    usart_send_str("AT\r\n");
    usart_recv_str(s, maxlen);
    _delay_ms(2000);
    usart_send_str("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
    usart_recv_str(s, maxlen);
    _delay_ms(2000);
    usart_send_str("AT+RST\r\n");
    usart_recv_str(s, maxlen);
    _delay_ms(2000);
    usart_send_str("AT+CWLAP\r\n");
    usart_recv_str(s, maxlen);
    _delay_ms(2000);
    usart_send_str("AT+CWJAP=\"***\",\"***\"\r\n");
    usart_recv_str(s, maxlen);
}

int main(void) {
    usart_init();
    _delay_ms(5000);
    esp8266_test();

    for (;;) {
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program, I start getting the following response from the ESP8266.

```
18:53:19.380 -> sl⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮U)⸮⸮
18:53:19.547 -> ready
18:53:25.705 -> WIFI DISCONNECT
```

EDIT: working code

As pointed out by the [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/661242/331703), my program was basically garbage, riddled with errors (reading from UART and baud rate). But based on the answer, I revised the program and am able to connect to WiFi from code now. Following is the revised program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

#define BAUD 115200
#define F_CPU 16000000UL 

static void usart_init(void) {
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
#if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
#else
    UCSR0A &= ~(1 << U2X0);
#endif
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

static void usart_send_byte(uint8_t data) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
        ;
    UDR0 = data;
}

static uint8_t usart_recv_byte(void) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)))
        ;
    return UDR0;
}

static void usart_recv_line(char *s, uint8_t n) {
    uint8_t c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1 && (c = usart_recv_byte()) != '\n'; i++) {
        if (c != '\r')
            s[i] = c;
    }
    s[i] = 0;
}

static void usart_send_line(const char *s) {
    const uint8_t maxlen = 255;
    char buf[maxlen];

    buf[0] = 0;

    for (; *s; s++)
        usart_send_byte(*s);
    usart_send_byte('\r');
    usart_send_byte('\n');

    while (strcmp(buf, "OK") != 0 && strcmp(buf, "ERROR") != 0 && strcmp(buf, "ready") != 0)
        usart_recv_line(buf, maxlen);
}

static void esp8266_test() {
    usart_send_line("AT");
    _delay_ms(1000);
    usart_send_line("AT+CWMODE=1");
    _delay_ms(1000);
    usart_send_line("AT+RST");
    _delay_ms(1000);
    usart_send_line("AT+CWLAP");
    _delay_ms(5000);
    usart_send_line("AT+CWJAP=\"***\",\"***\"");
}

int main(void) {
    usart_init();
    _delay_ms(5000);
    esp8266_test();

    for (;;) {
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not add your solution to your question. Instead write an own answer for future visitors to clearly recognize it as such. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to receive data will never work.

For example, 4096 won't fit into 8-bit variable so it will be 0.

In addition, the ATMega328 which is running that code does not even have 4096 bytes of memory.